# How to modify database without deleting the data in firebase

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have 2 activities which enter data to the database of the same child... i put the data into database in the first activity and when i put from the second activity it replaces the existing data... how do i add without replacing... i dont want to add all data from one activity bcause i need to pass a lot of strings which might return null so how do i do it

1st activity

```
addData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String name = input_name.getText().toString();

            HashMap<String, String> userMap = new HashMap<>();
            userMap.put("Unique", Uid);
            userMap.put("Name", name);
//                userMap.put("Status", "Hey There");
//                userMap.put("Image", "Default");
//                userMap.put("Thumb_image", "Default");
            userMap.put("Phone_Number", mNumber);

            mdatabase.setValue(userMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
```

2nd activity

```
private void updateDisplayPicture() {
                    HashMap<String, String> userMap = new HashMap<>();
            userMap.put("Image", downloadUrl);
            userMap.put("Thumb_image", "Default");


            mdatabase.setValue(userMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Profile Successfully Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        startActivity(new Intent(SetUpProfileDisplayPicture.this, HomeScreen.class));
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second activity the values that you are adding are overwriting the values that you had in the first activity.

You need to pass the values in the first activity to the second activity and add them again:

```
  HashMap<String, String> userMap = new HashMap<>();
        userMap.put("Image", downloadUrl);
        userMap.put("Thumb_image", "Default");
        userMap.put("Unique", Uid);
        userMap.put("Name", name);
        userMap.put("Phone_Number", mNumber);
```

Or you can add `push()` in the second activity, thus preventing the values being overwritten:

```
 mdatabase.push().setValue(userMap)
```

Or you can use `updateChildren()`:

To simultaneously write to specific children of a node without overwriting other child nodes, use the `updateChildren()` method.

```
HashMap<String, String> userMap = new HashMap<>();
        userMap.put("Image", downloadUrl);
        userMap.put("Thumb_image", "Default");
mdatabase.updateChildren(userMap);
```

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#updating_or_deleting_data